# xmlhttprequest with username and password

Tags: javascript, ajax, xmlhttprequest, passwords

For a project i need to show on my website a still image of a camera image. But that image is password protected.
So in the past i found a solution but now i see that chrome doesn't accept that line of code anymore ..

So now i'm looking for another solution. I found a solution with xmlhttprequest but it doesn't work.

Can you help to fix the problem ? Here is my code with in command the code i used in the past.

Thanks !

```
img.onload = function(){



  // img.src = "http://admin:admin@10.13.8.14/media/cam0/still.jpg?res=max"+Math.random();
   img.src = XMLHttpRequest.open("GET", "http://10.13.8.14/media/cam0/still.jpg?res=max", "async", "admin", "admin" + Math.random());
   XMLHttpRequest.send();

};
```

Comment: Please, define "doesn't work"

Comment: TypeError: XMLHttpRequest.open is not a function